# Usage of word "jammy"

Tags: word-usage

I wonder if it's grammatically correct to say that the traffic is jammy. If so, does this sentence make sense at all?

Thanks

Comment: I don't say it's the last word on the subject, but I have some sympathy with [*Note that we don't say '**The traffic was jammed**' because it is the highway that was jammed, while the traffic was at a standstill.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22we+don%27t+say+The+traffic+was+jammed%27%22https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22we+don%27t+say+The+traffic+was+jammed%27%22) Personally, I'd be more likely to say [*The traffic was **jam-packed**.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22traffic+was+jam-packed%22)

Comment: One might be able to argue that the sentence is "grammatically correct," but that's not always a good indicator of whether or not it's a good way to express something.

Comment: @J.R. You're right. I probably should've also asked if the sentence is semantically correct as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Jammy" is a legitimate adjective, so the sentence is grammatically correct. It doesn't really make sense, though. Instead you could say the traffic is "jammed", but it's more common to just say traffic is "bad" or "backed up".

It is common however to use the word as a noun:

> There is a traffic jam.

Answer (score 5):

If you said this in Britain it would probably be misinterpreted.

[Jammy](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=jammy) is a synonym for lucky.

To say traffic was jammy could be interpreted as being lighter than usual.  You were lucky in not getting stuck.

You would be better saying that the traffic was jammed.

Comment: In the US, "jammy" would probably be interpreted as "like jam", so it doesn't work here either!

Comment: @stangdon: I didn't know Americans even *had* jam! I thought they always called it ***jelly***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Oh yes, [plenty of jams here.](http://www.smuckers.com/products/fruit-spreads)  I think [technically they are slightly different things](http://simmerandboil.cookinglight.com/2015/06/16/jam-vs-jelly-vs-preserves-whats-the-difference/) but in practice it might be just what we're used to saying.  "Grape jelly" and "strawberry jam" sound normal to me, but "grape jam" and "strawberry jelly" sound weird, even if they actually refer to indistinguishable things.  I am not going to claim this makes any sense.  :^)

Comment: @stangdon: Sounds like it's at least *similar* to the BrE distinction (insofar as we're talking about the stuff that comes in glass jars that we spread on bread & butter). *Jelly* is significantly less common (both as a product and a usage), but it's normally reserved for "smooth, homogeneous" products (often relatively "transparent, translucent"). Strawberry / raspberry jelly might include some of the small "pits", but they wouldn't have identifiable pieces of the fruit itself. Also, there's the "mechanical" aspect - jelly tends to slide on butter, jam *sticks* better, but slowly "runs" more.

Comment: @stangdon Have you visited a grocery store in the U.S. recently? You will find shelves stocked with jars marked "Grape Jam!" (We pefer Smuckers, but there are multiple choices.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers there are technical distinctions: Jelly is made from the juice of the fruit; Jam is made from the juice and pulp; Preserves are made from the whole fruit (think strawberry); and of course Marmalade is made with the juice and rind

Comment: @G. Ann - SonarSource Team: Hmm. I'm no chef (and certainly no expert in the making of preserves), but I don't really see a meaningful distinction between the *juice* and the *fruit* with something like strawberry jelly. Surely you'd just mash it all to a homogeneous paste, maybe strain out some of the pits and any surviving bigger bits, then boil it up with sugar & pectin (or whatever it is they use that gives jelly a different consistency to jam). Or if you want *jam*, you wouldn't mash it up so much (or strain it).

Comment: @P.E.Dant - Yes, I am in the US and I do visit grocery stores.  For some reason [grape jelly just seems a lot more common than grape jam](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=grape+jelly%2Cgrape+jam&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgrape%20jelly%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgrape%20jam%3B%2Cc0), though.

Comment: @stangdon Depends on the locality, probably. We like [strawberry jelly](https://www.google.com/express/product/4065916708470605170_2106560682124141157_100915900?ei=7Y-jV-C4NoWZBa-9pIAN&ved=0EOEqCA4), too. Any excuse to ingest more high fructose corn syrup!

Answer (score 1):

I would say "The traffic is jammed up" or "The traffic is backed up"; I would not say "jammy".  "Jammy" means "of or relating to the jam that you would put on your toast".  I think it has other meanings, too, but I'm speaking from an American English standpoint; not British English.